# FeynCalc error: FeynCalc`ComplexConjugate`Private`diracChainCC?

Tags: complex, feyncalc

I am trying to evaluate an amplitude. It is an electron-positron annihilation into $W^{-}W^{+}$ bosons. I am only considering the channel for a photon mediator, that is, $e^{-}e^{+} \rightarrow \gamma \rightarrow W^{-}W^{+}$. I wrote:

```
amp = 
 SpinorVBar[p1, Subscript[m, e]] (-I g GAD[\[Mu]]) SpinorU[p2, 
   Subscript[m, e]] (-I MT[\[Mu], \[Nu]]/q^2) ComplexConjugate[
   PolarizationVector[
    k2, \[Sigma]]] (-I g (MT[\[Rho], \[Sigma]] FV[k1 - k2, \[Nu]] + 
      MT[\[Sigma], \[Nu]] FV[k2 - q, \[Rho]] + 
      MT[\[Nu], \[Rho]] FV[q - k1, \[Sigma]])) PolarizationVector[
   k1, \[Rho]]
```

But when I get the complex conjugate one,

```
ComplexConjugate[amp]
```

besides a readable part, it also gives

```
 FeynCalc`ComplexConjugate`Private`diracChainCC(\[Gamma]^\[Mu] (\[CurlyPhi](-Overscript[p1, _],Subscript[m, e])) (\[CurlyPhi](Overscript[p2, _],Subscript[m, e])))
```

Can someone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! It is difficult to give you some help if we cannot reproduce the problem. Please edit the question by including the code you are using and is causing the trouble. If the code is very long, make it a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I appreciate your comment. Thank you for this suggestion. I just did it.

Comment: Please include also the definition for `Mdiag1`.

Comment: I think Dirac spinors and matrices need `.` (`Dot`) for (non-commutative) multiplication.

Comment: I am sorry, Domen. I was trying other things and put here the wrong sign. However, that is not what is causing the error. I changed again, it remains.

Comment: @JacintoPaulo, have you tried tueda's suggestion? It seems to work.

Comment: Yeap!! It works! Thanks tueda :) the error disappeared.